# desiginig a job to count the number of active connections in oracle database

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

I am using oracle DB 11g, now as i am monitoring the performance of oracle DB which is connected to my java application , so rite now i have to monitior the counnt of active connections in DB at regular intervals lets say after every 30 minutes  below is the query which return me the count of active users along with there name and count

```
select distinct osuser, count(osuser) as active_conn_count 
from v$session 
group by osuser 
order by active_conn_count desc
```

now please  advise how can i make an job in oracle DB itself that will get triggered at every 30 minutes , and capture the  above query result that is the count of active connections as per the user and also Oracle DB memory usage at that time

folks please advise for this so that i can design the job and configure it in oracle DB  scheduler itself , something like `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB`

Folks please advise early he'll will be much appreciated as I am stuck up on this how can I configure the same in job

Comment: Is your question, "how do i specify a calendar for dbms_scheduler"?

Comment: @DavidAldridge well i want to make DBMS scheduler job nd the above query to be placed in stored procedure itself and i will configure the timings in scheduler itself

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `distinct` is useless in your query

Comment: Thanks request you to please advise I want to concert in dams scheduler job so first I need to put the above query in stored procedure and then a job,  request you to please advise how to achieve the same